# Python post request response status is "200" but when nothing is getting posted in the desired page

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests, file-transfer

I'm trying to upload(send) a file through python http post method.Something like this

```
import requests
#file = open('dummy.tar','rb')
with open('dummy.tar','rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('http://artifact.swf.daimler.com/artifactory/apricotbscqal/build/rusi_delta_lb/', files={'dummy.tar': f})
 if r.ok:
     print(r.status_code)
     print("Upload completed successfully!")
 else:
     print("Something went wrong!")
```

The status is showing 200 but when I check the destination link, this particular file(dummy.tar) doesn't seem to be present.How to resolve this? Is there any other way to upload files in python?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), `files` argument is a dictionary where the keys are the html form field names.
For example, if your form has a `filename` field like:

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
```

Then your code should be:

```
import requests

with open('dummy.tar','rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('http://artifact.swf.daimler.com/artifactory/apricotbscqal/build/rusi_delta_lb/', files={'filename': f})
    if r.ok:
        print(r.status_code)
        print("Upload completed successfully!")
    else:
        print("Something went wrong!")
```

That could be the reason why you are getting status 200 but no file uploaded.

Comment: Sorry still getting the same result, is there a different way to upload?